# Wait for a file to be created with a timeout

Tags: vb6, filesystems, timeout, wait

I am trying to make a vb6 prog to wait for the creation of a pdf file.
Right now I'm just making a pause of 3 sec like that :

```
startTime = Time
endTime = TimeValue(startTime) + TimeValue(TimeSerial(0,0,3))
While endTime > Time
Wend

If FSO.FileExists(sPdfFileName) Then
    OkCreatedPDF = True
Else
    OkCreatedPDF = False
End If
```

but some times the pdf creation takes more that 3 sec. So I'd like to wait for the file to be created but with a timeout (says 10sec). I prefer not to extend the waiting time as this will be run a thousand times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Sleep` with  1000 ms, it means it will wait for 1 second until it keeps running the code, using a flag variable called `sTimeout` you can define a number of seconds it will run the loop, I hard coded 10 but you can make another variable for setting the seconds,  every second it will run the loop and increase `sTimeout` by one, once it reaches 10 it will finish the `while` loop.

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Function GeneratePDF()
    Dim sTimeout as Integer

    Call YourPDFroutine()

    StatusLabel.Caption = "Wait until PDF is finished..."
    While FSO.FileExists(sPdfFileName) = False
        sTimeout = sTimeout + 1
        Sleep 1000
        If sTimeOut > 10 Then
            OkCreatedPDF = False
            StatusLabel.Caption = "ERROR: Timeout!"
            Exit Function
        End If
    Wend

    OkCreatedPDF = True
    StatusLabel.Caption = "The PDF " & sPdfFileName & " was generated!"
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the timeout. I used the sleep API with a counter, if reach 10 then exit the function. Hope this can helps you

Comment: Thank you @MadAntrax, I'm a bit new to the old VB6 :) So sleep is a command provided by the kernel32.dll ?

Comment: Sleep is an API, a function stored in a Windows library (kernel32.dll) that you can use. vb6 have no native function to "wait" between instructions, every time you need to do something that is not implemented natively, you can use API calls to achieve it

Comment: OK not sure if I can call this API in my case (the vbcode will be run inside an app I can't modify) will let you know. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a VB6 env in from of me just now...but regardless... I made a few tweaks to your original code.  In case the API approach cant be used, you can try this :

```
startTime = Time

endTime = TimeValue(startTime) + TimeValue(TimeSerial(0,0,10))

While endTime > Time 

If FSO.FileExists(sPdfFileName) Then
    OkCreatedPDF = True
    Exit While
Else
    OkCreatedPDF = False
    DoEvents()
End If

Wend
```

Comment: Changed the time delay to 10, put the FSO Check inside the while.  If file found, break out of the while loop so the whole 10 seconds wont have to elapse if the file shows up sooner.  Add a DoEvents statement to the false side of the IF so that you don't hog the CPU while this is running.   g'luck.